# Interpret periods from fourier transfrom graph of periodic impulse signals

Tags: fourier-transform

I have obtained the fourier transform of a signal with following graph

[image]

My question (though might be too junior for the professionals in signal processing field) is: how can we extract the period of `30` from the `fourier transform mag` graph?

The source code is

```
Fs = 1;
Ts = 1/Fs;
dt = 0:Ts:30*4-Ts;

 y1 = [
  100 ; zeros(Fs*29,1);
  100 ; zeros(Fs*29,1);
  100 ; zeros(Fs*29,1);
  100 ; zeros(Fs*29,1);
  ];

subplot(4,1,1)
plot(dt, y1, 'r')
title('impulse happen in time series', 'fontsize', 18);

X = fft(y1);
X_mag = abs(X)
subplot(4,1,2)
plot(X_mag)
title('fourier transform mag', 'fontsize', 18);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are in the continuous-time domain, given the periodic impulse train with a period of $T_0$

$$ x(t) = \sum_k \delta(t - k T_0)$$

then its CTFT will be another periodic impulse train in the frequency domain 
$$ X(\omega) = \frac{2\pi}{T_0} \sum_k \delta( \omega - k\omega_0)$$

Where the period $\omega_0$ of the frequency impulses is related to the period of the time impulses as

$$ \omega_0= \frac{2\pi}{T_0} $$

hence the time period will be given as:

$$ T_0 = \frac{2\pi}{\omega_0} $$

In your case, if $T_0 = 30$  then $\omega_0$ will be 
$$ \omega_0 = \frac{2\pi}{30} = \frac{\pi}{15} $$

Conversely, given the frequency period as $\frac{2\pi}{30}$ then the corresponding time period will be $T_0 =  30$.

Note that there will be errors in your computation depending on how you simulate the impulse train or CTFT.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My original intention is to extract T0 out of Fourier transform in frequency domain, it turns out given the relation of 2*Pi = T0 * W0, I come to the original question again, that is how to extract W0 in the graph.